# Слетел перевод разделов на странице участников

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-участников

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переводы были обновлены ещё на прошлой неделе, но подкачку из transifex, видимо, никто не сделал или просто ещё не было пересборки, на сайте пока пятничная ревизия `rev 2019.3.22.33110`. Строки слетели потому-то наконец-то [поправили капитализацию табов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325568/339911), правда не до конца.